# Add ActsAsTaggableOn Model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm currently using ActsAsTaggableOn successfully in my app and it's great.

Now I wish to expand functionality by allowing Tags to be searchable using my sites Searchkick function and also add Friendly ID to Tags.

The problem is that to do so, both of these require changes in the Tag model file.  As I have not created that model I'm unsure where to add these changes.

How do I add onto the Tag model that ActsAsTaggableOn provides?